# Разметки списка товаров вукомерс

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Имею вукомерс на вордпресс.
На странице списка товаров КАТЕГОРИИ я выбрал показывать И ПОДКАТЕГОРИИ И ТОВАРЫ .
Разметка имеет примерно такой вид

```
<ul class="products columns-4">
  <li class="product-category product first"> 1</li>
  <li class="product-category product">2 </li>

  <li class="product type-product"> 3</li>
  <li class="product type-product"> 4</li>
  <li class="product type-product"> 5</li>
  <li class="product type-product"> 6</li>
</ul>
```

Где находится, какой файл отвечает за разметку этой страницы.
Я нашел файлы формирования LI и UL/
а как формируется порядок на странице,

вообщем мне надо все `product-category`
и все `product type-product` обернуть в отдельные `дивы`,
сейчас я это делаю скриптом, но хочется по людски.

Answer (score 0):

Все шаблоны вукоммерс находятся у них в плагине в папке templates. Можно посмотреть у них на репозитории: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/master/templates. Смотрите хуки которые вам нужны и в functions.php пишите их. Код для вашей задачи выглядит примерно так:

```
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_product_loop_start', 'woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories' ); //Отключаем стандартный вывод подкатегорий
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'my_subcategories', 10 ); // Нужно поставить правильный приоритет в зависимости от темы
function my_subcategories() {
    woocommerce_output_product_categories( 
        [
            'parent_id' => get_queried_object_id(),
            'before'    => '<ul class="products columns-' . esc_attr( wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' ) ) . '">',
            'after'     => '</ul>',
        ]
    );
}
```